# Unable to import modules like evolve_graph_network

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to detect anomalies in a bitcoin dataset and I am quite new to this section. The research paper I follow used Graph convolution network and need these modules. I am unable to import them. Please let me know how will I install them.

```
import graph_utils
import custom_lstm_cell 
import evolve_graph_network as egcn
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-038aefedfc7c> in <module>
----> 1 import graph_utils
      2 import custom_lstm_cell
      3 import evolve_graph_network as egcn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graph_utils'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-afdcaaef6f5f> in <module>
----> 1 import custom_lstm_cell
      2 import evolve_graph_network as egcn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_lstm_cell'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-623905ff7160> in <module>
----> 1 import evolve_graph_network as egcn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'evolve_graph_network'
```

Comment: hi, have you tried on cmd line:
pip install graph_utils

Comment: I did. These are custom made libraries and are not publicly available.

Comment: If they are custom made libraries you have to ask whoever made them, give them to you. You need to have them in the same directory in which your file, which imports them is present.